# How to preserve fermented bean sauce

Tags: food-preservation

How can I can and preserve my fermented bean sauce so it has a long shelf life preferably one year or longer. I ferment the beans in smoke and in low heat and then stir fry them in mustard oil, garlic, sesame seeds, turmaric, salt and ginger. I am the only one in the house who eats this yummy smelly sauce. If I can't prolong its shelf life I will have to throw away a lot of it.
Thanks

Comment: Someone else will come along to advise about canning, I don't know much about that. I *do* know that you can freeze it. How much sauce do you need to preserve? Do you have the freezer space? If so, I'm happy to give you advice on how to do it well.

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you mean by 'fermenting in smoke'. Fermenting is generally accepted as being encouraging natural lacto-bacillus production in the food by using brine and controlling the temperature of your jar or crock within a certain (coolish) range for days/weeks. This process preserves the food to an extent, but must then be kept in the fridge which slows down decay but doesn't halt it like pickling in vinegar, canning or freezing food does. A tip with fermented foods is that the significant health benefits are lost if you heat them, better to add them on top of heated food at the end.

If what you're actually doing is smoking (rather than fermenting), then shelf-life will depend on a) whether it is a cold smoking or hot smoking process you are using; b)how long you are smoking for and c) how you store it (under oil, in a sterile jar, etc).